# How to mix grid/screen types in brightscript?

Tags: brightscript

How can I use multiple screen types on the same screen?
For example, how can I show the posterscreen on top and then the gridscreen at the bottom

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Most screen types are full-screen and even the ones that aren't (roMessageDialog, roPinEntryDialog), they are still [modal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window) (meaning they limit focus/interaction to themselves).

You can show some type of screens on top of others but that inactivates the ones below till the top screen is closed. You can write your own

If push comes to shove, you can write your own screen from scratch by using roScreen or roImageCanvas.